# Do all WordPress installations include WP CLI by default

Tags: wp-cli

Does the standard WordPress installation include WP CLI? So if someone install WordPress on their website does it automatically include WP CLI?

Answer (score 3):

WP-CLI is not part of the WordPress software itself. It’s something that gets installed on the server, but you don’t need to install any plugins or anything in WordPress for it to work.

Whether or not you can use WP-CLI depends on whether your host has it installed, or let’s you install it, and whether they give you the SSH access necessary to use it.